# how to do filter and pagination in the vuejs

Tags: vue.js

i want to do filter and pagination in my view-candidates page..i want to display the candidates depending on the name and experience and expected ctc..i want to display the candidates..
Can anyone help me how to do that in vuejs...

Here is my view-candidates.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <el-row :gutter="12">
        <el-col>
      <p>View Candidates</p>
    </el-col>
        </el-row>

    <el-row :gutter="12">
        <template v-for="c in candidates">
            <el-col :span="6">
            <Candidate :c="c" :key="c.id"></Candidate>
            </el-col>
        </template>
    </el-row>
</div>
```

here is my view-candidates.js page:

```
import Candidate from './components/Candidate.vue';
 const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
    return {
        candidates: window.data.candidates,
        sortKey : 'first_name'
    }
},
components: { Candidate },
```

});

here is my candidate.vue page:

```
<template>
<ElCard>
    <div slot="header">
      <strong>
        {{c.first_name.toUpperCase() + ' ' + c.last_name.toUpperCase()}}
        <br />
        <small>{{c.role}} - {{c.experience}} Years</small>
      </strong>
    </div>

    <p><strong>{{c.contact_no}} : {{c.email}}</strong></p>
    <p>
      <strong>Currently at:</strong> {{c.current_location}}
      <br />
      <strong>Ready to move:</strong> {{c.desired_location}}
    </p>

    <ElButton type="primary" size="small" @click="ResumeDialog = true">VIEW RESUME</ElButton>

    <ElDialog class="text-left" :title="c.first_name.toUpperCase() + ' ' + c.last_name.toUpperCase()" v-model="ResumeDialog">
        <p><strong>{{c.role}} - {{c.experience}} Years</strong></p>
        <p>
            <strong>Currently at:</strong> {{c.current_location}}
            <br />
            <strong>Ready to move:</strong> {{c.desired_location}}
        </p>
        <p>{{c.resume}}</p>
        <br />

        <p><strong>{{c.contact_no}} : {{c.email}}</strong></p>
    </ElDialog>
</ElCard>
```

//script

```
    import { Button as ElButton, Dialog as ElDialog, Card as ElCard } from 'element-ui';
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        props: ['c'],
        data() {
            return {
                ResumeDialog: false,
            }
        },
        components: { ElButton, ElDialog, ElCard },
    }
```

Can anyone help me how to do that..

TIA..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view-candidates.js it should be like that:

```
import Candidate from './components/Candidate.vue';
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      sortKey : 'first_name',
      page: 0,
      itemsPerPage: 4,
    }
  },
  components: { Candidate },
  methods: {
    //custom method bound to page buttons
    setPage(page) {
      this.page = page-1;
      this.paginedCandidates = this.paginate()
    },
    paginate() {
      return this.filteredCandidates.slice(this.page*this.itemsPerPage, this.itemsPerPage * this.page + this.itemsPerPage)        
    },
  },
  computed: {
    //compute number of pages, we always round up (ceil)
    numPages() {
      return Math.ceil(this.filteredCandidates.length/this.itemsPerPage);
    },
    filteredCandidates() {
      //filter out all candidates that have experience less than 10
      const filtered = window.data.candidates.filter((candidate) => {
        //e.g.
        if(candidate.experience < 10) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
      return filtered;
    },
    paginedCandidates() {
      return this.paginate()
    }
  }
});
```

And you render the buttons in the template:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <el-row :gutter="12">
       <el-col>
           <p>View Candidates</p>
       </el-col>
   </el-row>

   <el-row :gutter="12">
       <template v-for="c in paginedCandidates">
           <el-col :span="6">
               <Candidate :c="c" :key="c.id"></Candidate>
           </el-col>
       </template>
   </el-row>
   <el-row>
       <!-- setPage is our method defined in methods object -->
       <button v-for="n in numPages" @click="setPage(n)">@{{ n }}</button>
   </el-row>
</div>
```

I believe this should do the magic. Probably you'll have to adjust it a little bit to your needs.

Comment: thats it ?or else we need to write any code in another pages?

Comment: @user3663 I've added the page button mechanism. It's pretty simple. You just need to calculate number of pages which is numOfCandidates/itemsPerPage rounded UP (ceil func). Next you need to create loop numPages times. Then method setPage bounded to each that button. (The number of page needs to be lower down coz its 1 in button but we need to index from 0)

Comment: i got this error Use of undefined constant n - assumed 'n'

Comment: Ahhh, yeah, forgot that you are using blade and the syntax for variable is the same. It should be @{{ n }} instead of {{ n }} ;)